# Why would simple PHP Curl https POST requests take more than 30 seconds to complete, from a Mac machine?

Tags: php, php-curl

I am coding an API in PHP 7.2 to interface with a payment platform. I am doing that on a Mac (Catalina), and my project is reverse proxied by Nginx (Laravel Valet) on the Mac.

The simplest Curl requests take forever to complete. Like, 36 seconds (for only the curl_exec() function to execute), when the SAME request from the same machine takes 1.7 seconds with POSTMAN.

Any idea why that would be?

The Curl report seems fine (sanitised):

```
*   Trying xxx.0.xxx.78:443...
* Connected to api.paymentplatform.com (xxx.0.xxx.78) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem
  CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=Destination, Inc.; OU=Destination Production; CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com
*  start date: Jul 27 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  1 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'AfqL2fMLLxXhm6ZNQRtQmqGJKReMEL5jXJMVO4uqpadvIfx6YEAccIxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx'
> POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.paymentplatform.com
Authorization: Basic QWZxTDJmTUxMeFhobTZaTlFSdFFtcUdKS1JlTUVMNWpYSk1WTzR1cXBhZHZJZng2WUVBY2NJRm1fY2pob0RZTno2ZS1hV3B3QnhnWU1STlM6RUpSUzNrc1hhSFcybEhIZDAxMVh1Wkt4Y3ZqdXhzYS0wbmlhTWZ6Mzluaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en_US
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 29
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 29 out of 29 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Content-Length: 701
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Fri, 13 Nov 2020 13:45:13 GMT
< Destination-Debug-Id: b6e1e8dda1785
< X-Destination-Token-Service: IAAS
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.paymentplatform.com left intact
```

And the request seems simple enough (and identical to the POSTMAN one):

```
$curl = curl_init();
        $header = array(
            'Accept-Language: en_US',
            'Accept: application/json'
        );
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL             => VB_P['API_URL'].'/v1/oauth2/token',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            //CURLOPT_HEADER          => 'Accept: application/json',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => $header,
            //CURLOPT_HEADER        => 'Accept-Language: en_US',
            CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => "grant_type=client_credentials",
            CURLOPT_USERPWD         => VB_P['CLIENT_ID'].':'.VB_P['CLIENT_SECRET']
        ));

        if (VB_SERV_NAME == 'local') {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        }

        $time_start = microtime(true);
        $response_json = curl_exec($curl);
        $time_end = microtime(true);
```

Reading some messages on the web, I have tried to add  `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);curl_setopt($curl CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );`
but it doesn't change anything...

Many thanks!
E.

Comment: There are a lot of factors to consider here. If it's an external url, Geographical location, size of response, internet connection, etc 

Ideally, you can use this site to generate dummies http://dummy.restapiexample.com/ to test your code

try accessing the API link directly as well to see.

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right. In my case, I had a “misconfigured DNS resolver(s)”. Found out by running a Valet diagnostic. Some obsolete DNS declared in my Mac network settings...

For some reason, Postman did not mind, but PHP Curl was lost.

Stupid of me though.

E.